# Trying to use v-model and v-show on radio buttons to show different divs (Vue and Laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to make different divs show up according to the selected radio button option using v-model and v-show but, even though they stay hidden when the page is loaded as they should, they don't show up when a radio button is selected.

This code is a Vue component inside of a Laravel project. When I try this same code on https://jsfiddle.net/, using only Vue, it works exactly how it should. But when I try it inside my Laravel project, it doesn't work.

Component's HTML (don't mind the id and name values):

```
<div id="app">
    <div>
      <span><strong>*</strong> options </span>

      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="grerjSim" name="grerj" value="showYes" v-model="showOption">
        <label for="grerjSim"> yes </label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="grerjNao" name="grerj" value="showNo" v-model="showOption">
        <label for="grerjNao"> no </label>
      </div>

      <div v-show="showOption === 'showYes'">
        <span><strong>*</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </span>
        <input type="text" required>
      </div>

      <div v-show="showOption === 'showNo'">
        <label for="grerjMotivo">No
        <select id="grerjMotivo">
          <option>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</option>>
        </select>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component's JS:

```
<script>
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  showOption: value=""
 }
})
</script>
```

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Did you add the JS script tag to your HTML? Any errors in your console?

Comment: Yes, the component's JS is inside of the script tag. And no, no errors on the console while running npm run watch or php artisan serve

Comment: Is the `showOption: value=""` in your Vue file a typo, or is it actually like that? Because that isn't valid.

Comment: maybe change `showOption: value=""` to `showOption: 'showNo'` ?

Comment: @AkenRoberts That's technically valid JavaScript because the OP's script does not have `'use strict'`. It's currently declaring a new `var` named `value`, setting it to the empty string, and the result is assigned to `showOption`.

Comment: In JSFiddle, the code runs fine with either showOption: value=" " or value=null. But on my Laravel project, the conditional rendering that I want from v-show and v-model simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that your Vue-related JavaScript is inside its own `<script>` tag, which I assume means you're writing the Vue code in your Blade template.

While you *can* get Vue apps working that way, it's easier to manage if you keep your JavaScript contained in the source files located in `resources/js`. There is even an [example already there](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/6f3d68f67f3dab0e0d853719696ede8dfd9cc4e1/resources/js/app.js#L30-L32) for you to customize.

Also, when I asked if you checked your console for any errors, I meant your [web browser's developer tools console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools). If you haven't checked that yet, it may hold a very obvious clue in the form of a specific error.

Here are a couple errors that your console might have:

> ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

This means you added the Vue app code (`new Vue({ ... })`), but no other JavaScript including the Vue library, so the code doesn't know what Vue is.

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "showOption" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

If you tried to fix the undefined Vue error above by [running Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#running-mix) and adding a `<script>` tag for the built file, you might see this. That's because the default Mix source code has an example Vue app targeting `#app` already, so the two are conflicting and the one in `app.js` is winning.

You'll either want to remove your Blade file Vue app and customize the default one in `app.js` (recommended), or remove the `app.js` one and keep the Blade file.

[Official documentation on using Laravel Mix with JavaScript.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#working-with-scripts)

Comment: I finally managed to fix it. It turns out that I skipped some basic Vue concepts about component registration, reactivity and managing errors on the dev tools console, like you said, when learning conditional rendering. Thanks!